# Character in last position only to be replaced - Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a situation where I want to replace only the last character in a column in hive based on certain conditions. 
My code is as follows,

```
select 
case 
    when amtsv111 >= 0 then 
    case 
        when substring(amtsv111,-1,1) = '0' then regexp_replace(amtsv111,substring(amtsv111,-1,1),'{')
        when substring(amtsv111,-1,1) = '1' then regexp_replace(amtsv111,substring(amtsv111,-1,1),'A')
        end
```

So for this code, I get result as:

```
15101    A5A0A
```

Whereas I want the result as follows:

```
15101    1510A
```

Can someone please help me with the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select (case when amtsv111 like '%0' then concat(substring(amtsv111, 1, length(amtsv111) - 1), '{'
             when amtsv111 like '%1' then concat(substring(amtsv111, 1, length(amtsv111) - 1), 'A'
             else amtsv111
        end)
```